# three way binding returns $bindTo is not a function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Hi I have the following setup to bind my FirebaseArray in angularjs in order to sync the list when a date changes.

```
var vm = this;

vm.startDate = {
  startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
  endDate: moment().endOf('month')
};
vm.bonnen = $firebaseArray(bonCollection($rootScope.user.uid, vm.startDate.startDate, vm.startDate.endDate));
vm.bonnen.$bindTo(vm, "vm.startDate");
```

However, I keep getting the following error

> Error: vm.bonnen.$bindTo is not a function. (In 'vm.bonnen.$bindTo(vm, "vm.startDate")', 'vm.bonnen.$bindTo' is undefined)

What am I possibly doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

$bindTo is only available for $firebaseObject

Docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-bindtoscope-varname

Discussion on why it can't be: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/600

Comment: Is there any alternative on how to resync my firebaseArray when the date changes?

Comment: You should read over the documentation, it explains how to do this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex

Comment: I have read the documentation, however, I only see explained remote updates on the server and not if a update is done locally. Could you perhaps help me out with some example code?